# Where to submit UX feedback for the Stack Exchange app (Android)

Tags: support, android-app

I'm looking to submit some suggestions about the user interface/experience for the Stack Exchange app for Android. Where/what medium should be used to provide feedback?  Should it be via direct email, or is there an online bug reporting and wishlist forum?

[image: Android stack exchange app version info]

Comment: FYI, it's been unmaintained for years.

Comment: It's definitely still getting at least basic maintenance, version 1.0.95 was updated June 30, 2017, although it could have just been for android core updates

Comment: As to your question, check the 'About' menu item in the app.

Comment: Talk about 'meta' - the links in the about menu trigger posting back here or filtering for questions with the tag android-app!  Thanks. I guess I'll submit requests and bugs individually to the stack.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

If that feedback also has suggestions for improvement, the place is right here on Meta Stack Exchange. If you have multiple suggestions, split them into several [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s. Explain in each one how your suggestion would make the app better.

If the feedback is just for the sake of feedback (e.g., "the app isn't good"), then I'm afraid there is no place in Stack Exchange this will be on-topic. Feel free to post this in a personal blog or in a review on the Google Play Store, and link to it in your profile.

There's no point contacting the team about it, because, at some point in 2017, Stack Exchange disbanded its mobile app team, and the Android app is no longer being developed. It still exists, it's still up and running, but no changes will be made to the app, and no non-critical bugs will be fixed. (Only new fatal bugs causing the app to stop working and critical security bugs will be fixed.)

Comment: You love changing your display name, *so much*. Next time maybe ***SWhiazdaorwd***?

Comment: @iDeb nah it must always start with "Sha". ;)

Comment: Sha-blah-blah *sounds* rocking and rocking!

Comment: @iDebug if anything, [Sha La La](https://m.soundcloud.com/dunga-mattos-dj/jason-derulo-swalla-dmattos-sha-la-la-remix-1) rocks! :D

Comment: I approved an edit with the intention to then undo one small part (changing "this year" back to 2017), but I did it wrong and now I can't fix it until the review clears.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @Monica all good, that anonymous editor is good, and Cody brought back the year.